# Add fixed sized nodes in a scope to pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

i want to have a scope with a rectangular node that (see red rectangle in screenshot below)...

- sits just above the plot
- is centered at 30 (axis coordinates)
- spans 60 (axis coordinates)

In my code so far i have to manually shift the scope up in terms of the axis coordinates. Also `minimum width=60` makes the node only about 25 long.
I have to use the scope as i will add several other nodes to it.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
clip mode=individual,
]
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,135)}]
\node[rectangle,draw,inner sep=0,minimum width=60,minimum height=0.25cm] (arc1) at (30,0) {};
\end{scope}

\addplot [thick,red]
table {%
0.0 102.0237699221741
0.25 101.72068526496476
15.0 45.16414016873146
30.0 17.64127821777247
45.0 45.16414016873147
59.75 101.7206852649648
60.0 102.02376992217408
};

\addplot [thick]
table {%
0.0 17.64106301486778
0.25 17.697226406877196
15.0 45.163818883512945
30.0 102.02354812212525
45.0 45.163818883512945
59.75 17.697226406877185
60.0 17.64106301486777
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: so far]

EDIT:
Later i'll include many nodes inside the scope. The line with rectangles is defined in another tikzpicture. But to avoid nesting tikzpictures i'm copying the content inside the scope, like so:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
clip mode=individual,
]
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,135)}]
\draw (-5,0) -- (65,0);
\node[rectangle,fill=white,draw,inner sep=0,minimum width=10,minimum height=0.25cm] (arc1) at (10,0) {};
\node[rectangle,fill=white,draw,inner sep=0,minimum width=10,minimum height=0.25cm] (arc1) at (15,0) {};
\node[rectangle,fill=white,draw,inner sep=0,minimum width=20,minimum height=0.25cm] (arc1) at (30,0) {};
\node[rectangle,fill=white,draw,inner sep=0,minimum width=10,minimum height=0.25cm] (arc1) at (60,0) {};
\end{scope}

\addplot [thick,red]
table {%
0.0 102.0237699221741
0.25 101.72068526496476
15.0 45.16414016873146
30.0 17.64127821777247
45.0 45.16414016873147
59.75 101.7206852649648
60.0 102.02376992217408
};

\addplot [thick]
table {%
0.0 17.64106301486778
0.25 17.697226406877196
15.0 45.163818883512945
30.0 102.02354812212525
45.0 45.163818883512945
59.75 17.697226406877185
60.0 17.64106301486777
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Please, can you provide a sketch of an example of final figure? Wha it is in this nodes? I don't see why `scope`  should be needed.

Answer (score 2):

One option for the width might be to use the `let` syntax from the `calc` TikZ-library to calculate the distance of 60 x-axis units. Did you want a different method for the shifting?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
clip mode=individual,
]

\addplot [thick,red]
table {%
0.0 102.0237699221741
0.25 101.72068526496476
15.0 45.16414016873146
30.0 17.64127821777247
45.0 45.16414016873147
59.75 101.7206852649648
60.0 102.02376992217408
};

\addplot [thick]
table {%
0.0 17.64106301486778
0.25 17.697226406877196
15.0 45.163818883512945
30.0 102.02354812212525
45.0 45.163818883512945
59.75 17.697226406877185
60.0 17.64106301486777
};

\begin{scope}[shift={(0,135)}]
\path let \p1=(0,0), \p2=(60,0) in
node[rectangle,draw,inner sep=0,minimum width=\x2-\x1,minimum height=0.25cm] (arc1) at (30,0) {};
\end{scope}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you explain what the problem is? Placing the node at 30 works, so there seems to be ans issue with the node width using another coord system?
Is there another way? And how would i replace the scope shifting with this?

Comment: @MarvinNoll I don't know the technical details of why the width setting doesn't work, so no, I can't explain it :) This isn't a replacement for the scope shifting though. I mean, it's easy to place the node without the shifting, but it's not entirely clear to me why you need to use a `scope` in first place. If you explain how you're placing the other stuff in the `scope`, perhaps it would be clearer.

Comment: I've edited my original question. I will have dozens of nodes on a line above the plot. I'll get the node statements from another file copied in. So using let gets cumbersome fast. Also shifting the scope has to be done by hand based on the maximum of the y axis.

Comment: @MarvinNoll I see. I'm afraid I don't have any good ideas ...